# byte[] to String not working correctly

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, converters

Now from the previous question I got the NTLM handshake working. Now when I convert from the byte[] to a String I can't filter out the whitespaces. My result looks like this:

```
CHAR: A
CHAR:
CHAR: B
CHAR: 
CHAR: C

USERNAME: A B C
```

And this is the code producing this output:

```
username = new String( token, offset, length, "ISO-8859-1" );
username = username.trim();

char[] test = username.toCharArray();
for ( char t : test )
{
  if ( !Character.isWhitespace( t ) )
  {
    System.out.println( "CHAR: " + t );
  }
}
System.out.println( "USERNAME: " + username );
```

I even checked with `String.valueOf(t).isEmpty()` or `String.valueOf(t).equals(" ")`.
All the time it seems to be not the case and the chars are printed. I even used all at once with || but everyone is really "correct".

I get the Input like this from another class:

```
String auth = httpServletRequest.getHeader( "Authorization" );
String username = authService.getUserNameFromNTLM( auth.substring( 5 ));
```

and convert the String to an byte[] like this:

```
byte[] token = Base64.getDecoder().decode( msg );
```

The output I need is ABC. Can somebody tell me why my procedure is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the byte array is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-16?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the numeric value of your char and compared it to the expected numeric value of a space? Also setting a breakpoint in your IDE might work wonders.

Comment: @Henry I get a NTLM V3 token like in this article https://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html
My token looks something like this: TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHIAAAAYABgAigAAABQAFABAAAAADAAMAFQAAAASABIAYAAAAAAAAACiAAAAAYIAAFUAUgBTAEEALQBNAEkATgBPAFIAWgBhAHAAaABvAGQATABJAEcASABUAEMASQBUAFkArYfKbe/jRoW5xDxHeoxC1gBmfWiS5+iX4OAN4xBKG/IFPwfH3agtPEia6YnhsADT

Comment: This document says `username string (unicode UTF-16LE)`

Comment: Damn...I overlooked that. I will try to convert with UTF-16LE Charset right now.

Comment: @Henry if you could post that as an answer for me to accept it as solved? After changing the Charset to UTF-16LE in the new String() call its working perfectly now. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username in the message is encoded in UTF-16LE rather than ISO-8859-1.

What you currently see in the string are NUL characters originating from the wrong decoding.